# How to Configure Jms Queue in Jboss As7

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss7.x

I am trying to configure JMS in my Standalone Jboss as7 .but i cannot really added a queue in jboss as7.Actually I tried my stuff as much i can but i cannot get it. while searching most of the link told that add  in standalone.xml file . but after that i am getting exception only . some of the site told that to use **[standalone@localhost:9999 /] add-jms-queue --name=sampleQueue --entries=queue/sampleQueue** but i do no where i have to use .. so tell me how to add a queue/Topic in jBoss as 7.

Comment: Refer this link http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/helloworld-jms/

Comment: Found solution [link]http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/ejb3/remote-jms-client-and-ejb3-mdb-consumer-eclipse-jboss-7-1/

Answer (score 3):

First you have to configure standalone.xml to get JMS queue support. Because after JBoss AS 7, queue configurations removed from standalone.xml and added to the standalone-full.xml and standalone-ha.xml

To configure standalone.xml, follow steps in  [CONFIGURE A JMS QUEUE IN STANDALONE.XML OF JBOSS AS7](https://wadsashika.wordpress.com/2014/09/20/configure-a-jms-queue-in-standalone-xml-of-jboss-as7/)

after that, you can try the your procedure or you can mannually setup a queue by adding it to the standalone.xml. You should strat the JBoss server with default settings after configuring this.